# select xml node value by attribute

Tags: javascript, xml

I've created the following xml file and what I'm now trying to do is to do the steps:

```
   1.select MAP node
   2.select POINT node where po=1
   3.get POINTNAME value
   4.select RESULT_VALUE and get Value where val=100
```

I'm new in xml, what i know is the steps until xmlhttp.open("GET","xmltag.xml",false); 
 please help to do the above step in javascript

```
   <PRO>
    <MAP>
     <POINT po="1">
      <POINTNAME>point1</POINTNAME> 
      <RESULT_VALUE>
       <Value val="001">LL</Value >
       <Value val="010">L</Value >
       <Value val="011">L1</Value >
       <Value val="100">L2</Value >
       <Value val="101">H</Value >
       <Value val="110">H</Value >  
      </RESULT_VALUE>
     </POINT>
    </MAP>

    <VIEW> 
     <HOUSE1>
      <POINT po="1">
       <POINTNAME>SR_SD_LVL_001</POINTNAME> 
       <RESULT_VALUE>
        <Value val="001">LL</Value >
        <Value val="010">L</Value >
        <Value val="011">L1</Value >
        <Value val="100">L2</Value >
        <Value val="101">H</Value >
        <Value val="110">H</Value > 
       </RESULT_VALUE>
      </POINT> 
     </HOUSE1> 
    </VIEW> 
   </PRO>
```

Comment: Do you get a response? Have you set up a callback for the request and verified that it runs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for code directly, i think you need to grab some tutorial and start working on it on your own first.
Check: http://www.zachleat.com/web/selecting-xml-with-javascript/

Comment: hihi, i've tried but couldnt find select node by attribute. i've seen the linked page but it seems is doesnt select by attribute value